# Automating pulling csv files off google Trends

Tags: google-trends

pyGTrends does not seem to work. Giving errors in Python.

pyGoogleTrendsCsvDownloader seems to work, logs in, but after getting 1-3 requests (per day!) complains about exhausted quota, even though manual download with the same login/IP works flawlessly.

Bottom line: neither work. Searching through stackoverflow: many questions from people trying to pull csv's from Google, but no workable solution I could find...

Thank you in advance: whoever will be able to help. How should the code be changed? Do you know of another solution that works?

Here's the code of pyGoogleTrendsCsvDownloader.py

```py
    import httplib
    import urllib
    import urllib2
    import re
    import csv
    import lxml.etree as etree
    import lxml.html as html
    import traceback
    import gzip
    import random
    import time
    import sys

    from cookielib import Cookie, CookieJar
    from StringIO import StringIO


    class pyGoogleTrendsCsvDownloader(object):
    '''
    Google Trends Downloader
    Recommended usage: 
    from pyGoogleTrendsCsvDownloader import pyGoogleTrendsCsvDownloader
    r = pyGoogleTrendsCsvDownloader(username, password)
    r.get_csv(cat='0-958', geo='US-ME-500')
    '''
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        '''  
    Provide login and password to be used to connect to Google Trends
    All immutable system variables are also defined here
    '''
        
        # The amount of time (in secs) that the script should wait before making a request.
        # This can be used to throttle the downloading speed to avoid hitting servers too hard.
        # It is further randomized.
        self.download_delay = 0.25
        
        self.service = "trendspro"
        self.url_service = "http://www.google.com/trends/"
        self.url_download = self.url_service + "trendsReport?"
        
        self.login_params = {}
        # These headers are necessary, otherwise Google will flag the request at your account level
        self.headers = [('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0'),
                        ("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"),
                        ("Accept-Language", "en-gb,en;q=0.5"),
                        ("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate"),
                        ("Connection", "keep-alive")]
        self.url_login = 'https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service='+self.service+'&passive=1209600&continue='+self.url_service+'&followup='+self.url_service
        self.url_authenticate = 'https://accounts.google.com/accounts/ServiceLoginAuth'
        self.header_dictionary = {}
        
        self._authenticate(username, password)
        
    def _authenticate(self, username, password):
        '''
    Authenticate to Google:
    1 - make a GET request to the Login webpage so we can get the login form
    2 - make a POST request with email, password and login form input values
    '''
        
        # Make sure we get CSV results in English
        ck = Cookie(version=0, name='I4SUserLocale', value='en_US', port=None, port_specified=False, domain='www.google.com', domain_specified=False,domain_initial_dot=False, path='/trends', path_specified=True, secure=False, expires=None, discard=False, comment=None, comment_url=None, rest=None)
        
        self.cj = CookieJar()
        self.cj.set_cookie(ck)
        self.opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(self.cj))
        self.opener.addheaders = self.headers
        
        # Get all of the login form input values
        find_inputs = etree.XPath("//form[@id='gaia_loginform']//input")
        try:
            #
            resp = self.opener.open(self.url_login)
            
            if resp.info().get('Content-Encoding') == 'gzip':
                buf = StringIO( resp.read())
                f = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=buf)
                data = f.read()
            else:
                data = resp.read()
            
            xmlTree = etree.fromstring(data, parser=html.HTMLParser(recover=True, remove_comments=True))
            
            for input in find_inputs(xmlTree):
                name = input.get('name')
                if name:
                    name = name.encode('utf8')
                    value = input.get('value', '').encode('utf8')
                    self.login_params[name] = value
        except:
            print("Exception while parsing: %s\n" % traceback.format_exc())
        
        self.login_params["Email"] = username
        self.login_params["Passwd"] = password
        
        params = urllib.urlencode(self.login_params)
        self.opener.open(self.url_authenticate, params)
        
    def get_csv(self, throttle=False, **kwargs):
        '''
    Download CSV reports
    '''
        
        # Randomized download delay
        if throttle:
            r = random.uniform(0.5 * self.download_delay, 1.5 * self.download_delay)
            time.sleep(r)
        
        params = {
            'export': 1
        }
        params.update(kwargs)
        params = urllib.urlencode(params)
        
        r = self.opener.open(self.url_download + params)
        
        # Make sure everything is working ;)
        if not r.info().has_key('Content-Disposition'):
            print "You've exceeded your quota. Continue tomorrow..."
            sys.exit(0)
            
        if r.info().get('Content-Encoding') == 'gzip':
            buf = StringIO( r.read())
            f = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=buf)
            data = f.read()
        else:
            data = r.read()
        
        myFile = open('trends_%s.csv' % '_'.join(['%s-%s' % (key, value) for (key, value) in kwargs.items()]), 'w')
        myFile.write(data)
        myFile.close()
```

Comment: I have discussed the issue with the author of the original code and some of its users online on github. Neither knows how to fix it. One would hope that a larger community of stackoverflowers will have an easier time with this problem (presumably, relevant for many)... Cheers

Comment: Is nobody up for a challenge? I know nothing about cookies and alike, but I know someone out there knows lots...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14772235/automating-pulling-csv-files-off-google-trends

Answer (score 3):

Although I don't know python, I may have a solution. I am currently doing the same thing in C# and though I didn't get the .csv file, I got created a custom URL through code and then downloaded that HTML and saved to a text file (also through code). In this HTML (at line 12) is all the information needed to create the graph that is used on Google Trends. However, this has ***alot*** of unnecessary text within it that needs to be cut down. But either way, you end up with the same result. The Google Trends data. I posted a more detailed answer to my question here:

[Downloading .csv file from Google Trends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40647404/downloading-csv-file-from-google-trends)

Answer (score 1):

There is an alternative module named pytrends - https://pypi.org/project/pytrends/ It is really cool. I would recommend this.

Example usage:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd                        
from pytrends.request import TrendReq
pytrend = TrendReq()

#It is the term that you want to search
pytrend.build_payload(kw_list=["Eminem is the Rap God"])

# Find which region has searched the term
df = pytrend.interest_by_region()
df.to_csv("path\Eminem_InterestbyRegion.csv")
```

Potentially if you have a list of terms to search you could make use of "for loop" to automate the insights as per your wish.